# Primefaces are not getting converted to html code

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to use `primefaces 3.5` with existing `JSF 2.1` application. I have gone through the questions related to `Primefaces and JSF` but the problem is not resolved. I have referred  also. The following jars are present in the application

- primefaces-3.5.jar
- jsf-api-2.1.7.jar
- jsf-facelets-1.1.15.jar
- jsf-impl-2.1.7.jar
- richfaces-ui-3.3.3.FINAL.jar
- richfaces-impl-3.3.3.FINAL-FX.jar
- richfaces-api-3.3.3.Final.jar

Faces Servlet are referred in `Web.xml`file.

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet </servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.cactus </url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I tried to use `<h:head>`instead of`<head>` but i got the error that its not found

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<head>
<title>Facelets Tutorial</title>
</head>
<body>
<p:editor />
<p:spinner />
</body>
</html>
```

Once the code is compiled, i could see the source code of `xhtml` file, the other tags like `h:outputText` is getting converted to `html`  but `primefaces` tags are not converting to `html` code.

Please suggest me if any `jars` needs to be updated.

Comment: Could you please add xhtml namespace from the jsf page

Comment: Why downvote for this question, it is not yet resolved. Please provide some suggestions :)

Comment: Can anyone suggestion some solution on this ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add namespace in HTML tag

```
     xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"  



<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"  
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"  
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"  
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
```

For reference http://primefaces.org/gettingStarted.html

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. Yes i have added the same namespace. I am trying to add the code but there is a problem with formatting.

Comment: Could you please add JSF content to question.

Comment: How do you deploying the application.... Using tomcat.... go to the folder workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core and check the folder tmp0/wtpwebapps

Comment: Using eclipse, the primefaces jar is included in the classpath and deployment assembly.

Comment: Yes, its deployed.Thats why the other tag <h:outputText value="Hi" /> is converted to html and showed the output also.

Comment: Yes, i redeployed and tested. I am using Jboss 6 Server to deploy the application. I have set to deploy in jboss folder itself like jboss-5.1.0.GA_Server\server\default\deploy

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44707/discussion-between-radhamani-muthusamy-and-shashi)

Comment: Let us http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44707/discussion-between-radhamani-muthusamy-and-shashi